# how to upgrade my ADB version on my smartphone?

Tags: android, adb

While using ADB I get:

"adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (32); killing... ubuntu"

After checking the issue,
I have ADB (Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40) running on my PC Ubuntu workstation and I have an older version on my phone (Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32),
So can someone please explain me how can I update my ADB on my smartphone (The device is not rooted)?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

This is not about your smartphone. You are running multiple adb versions on your computer, adb server must be the same version as the client.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, got it!